# Client / Server conversation - am I doing it wrong?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I have a client/server application that I made using sockets.
The thing is, when I send a command requesting some information and wait for a reply I block untill that reply comes. This makes it harder to implement bidirecional requesting/responde.
Let me explain using one example:
The client can list files in a directory of the server, so I do someting like that in code:

Client code:
1- Send request command: LS /
2- Blocks waiting for the LS responde.
3- Get the file list.

The reason why I did that is that the Client may have to transfer a file, so I do:
1- Send request for transfering a file.
2- Blocks on read() waiting to see if the server accepts
3- Only if it does, send the file.

So it was fine untill I had to add the server the ability to request anything.
In my code, the client can request anything and get blocked waiting for a response.
The server might then send any request command that will make no sense for the responde the client is waiting for. This would screw the conversation.

One resolution I tought is to never block for a response.
I would send a request command, and then come back to wait for ANY request or response from the server, if a response arrives then I would send the file.
So the thing is will I have to add like an ID in each request/response pair to know which response is for which request?

PS: Im pretty lost in how to design a network conversation between hosts and have never read a book about desing patterns for network applications.

PS2: sry my bad english ;)

Comment: Just to add more info...I have a class client that all my methods are something like that(in Java):  public List<Directories> listRemoteDir(String dir) throws Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is an application-level [**`protocol`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol) between the server and the clients.

For your particular case the simplest way is for the server to say upfront what it is going to send next. Say, put a **message type** byte in front of the message. Say `0` means request, `1` means response, etc. Stick that into a `switch` statement and you are done.

It's a good idea to include message length in that header too, so the receiving code knows how many bytes to fetch from the network to get a complete message.

Comment: to get the correct message I use the string delimiter \r\n encoded in ISO-8859-1....If I do it bidirectional I will not be able to implement a method in the client like List<Directories> listRemoteDir(String dir) will I ???

Comment: Delimited messages are fine too. You just need a way to include message *type* somewhere in the beginning of the message. Let, say, first word/token be the type. Look, for example, at HTTP - the first token is the HTTP "method" - `GET`, `POST`, etc. it's effectively the message type.

Comment: Ok I will try that. Also I read about people wrapin messages in a class, is it a good practise?

Comment: It's probably a good idea - have some common code parse the raw bytes from the network, create message objects, then pass those around (instead of just strings).

Comment: hey Nikolai maybe you can help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027121/designclasses-methods-interfaces-of-real-time-applicationsserver-client        on this first question u answered I didnt express myself correctlly but now with code examples I think I may get a good answer... Thanks