# Design(Classes, methods, interfaces) of real time applications(server/client)

Tags: java, network-programming, network-protocols

I´ve been looking for a good book or article about this topic but didnt find much. I didnt find a good example - piece of code - for a specific scenario. Like clients/server conversation.
In my application´s protocol they have to send/recieve messages. Like:
Server want to send a file to a client
Client can accpet or no,
if he accepts, server will send bytes over the same connection/socket.
The rest of my application all uses blocking methods, server has a method

Heres what I did:

Server method:

```
public synchronized void sendFile(File file)
{
  //send messsage asking if I can send a file
  //block on read, waiting for client responde
  //if client answers yes, start sending the bytes
  //else return
}
```

Client methods:

```
public void reciveCommand()
{
   //read/listen for a command from socket
   //if is a send file command handleSendFileCommand();
   //after the return of handleSendFileCommand() listen for another command
}

public void handleSendFileCommand()
{
   //get the file server want to send
   //check if it already has the file
   //if it already has, then send a command to the socket saying it already has and return         
   //else send a command saying server can send the file
   //create a FileInputStream, recive bytes and then return method
}
```

I am 100% sure this is wrong because, there is no way server and clients would talk bidirecional, I mean, when server wants to send a command to a server, they have to follow an order of commands until that conversation is finished, only then, they can send/recive another sequence of commands. Thats why I made all methods that send requests synchronized

It didnt took me a lot of time to realize I need to study about design patterns for that kind of application...
I read about Chain of Responsibility design pattern but I dont get it how can I use it or another good design pattern in that situation.

I hope someone can help me with some code example-like.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`synchronized` keyword in Java means something completely different - it marks a method or a code block as a [*critical section*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) that only single thread can execute at a time. You don't need it here.

Then, a TCP connection *is* bi-directional on the byte-stream level. The synchronization between the server and a client is driven by the messages exchanged. Think of a client (same pretty much applies to the server) as a [**`state machine`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine). Some types of messages are acceptable in the current state, some are not, some switch the node into different state.

Since you are looking into design patterns, the [**`State pattern`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) is very applicable here.